# There is error in my python projects cannot find it

Tags: python

i was making Jarvis project on python, just for fun,i dowlanded all libraries
and it seems everything is good, but there is some problem I can not find out what is it,i will share both below

here is my python code :

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import webbrowser
import wikipedia
import os
import smtplib

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak('Goog Morning!')
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak('Goog Afternoon!')
    else:
        speak('Good Evening!')
    speak('Hi,how can i help you?')

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as sourse:
        print('Listening..')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(sourse)
    try:
        print('Recognizing..')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-ln')
        print(f'User Said {query}\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Say That Again')
        return 'None'
    return query

def sebdEmail(to,content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('email@gmail.com','********')
    server.sendmail('email@gmail.com',to,content)
    server.close()

if __name__== '__main__':
    wishMe()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('Searching it..')
            query = query.replace('wikipedia','')
            results = wikipedia.summary(query,sentences=2)
            speak('According to wikipedia..')
            print(results)
            speak(results)
        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            webbrowser.open('youtube.com')
        elif 'open google' in query:
            webbrowser.open('google.com')
        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            speak(f'Sir,the time is {strTime}')
        elif 'email to friend' in query:
            try:
                speak('what would you like i say')
                content = takeCommand()
                to = 'emailw@gmail.com'
                sebdEmail(to,content)
                speak('Sir,its done')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                speak('Sorry,im not able to send this one')
```

and here is error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "********", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****", line 9, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "********", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "*********", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "*********", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "*********", line 1, in <module>
    import comtypes.client  # Importing comtypes.client will make the gen subpackage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'comtypes'
```

hope you can help because I really don't know what to do

thanks for help!!!

Comment: The solution is in the last line of the error: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'comtypes'*. Try installing comtypes module. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'nsss' instead of 'sapi5'

Comment: hi, well,that helped, but there is another issue,'Could not find PyAudio; check installation',I will be really pleased if you would help me :)